# What is really happening when we do substitution in math

Tags: logic, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics, education

Consider a toy case. Suppose we have a+b=10. This basically informs us a relation between two unknown variables a and b, however there is not enough information for us to tell what values do a and b take.

Now suppose we have another piece of information a=4. The standard way of combining the two pieces is by substitution into a+b=10 and we get 4+b=10. Then through math manipulation we can conclude b=6.

But what exactly is happening when we do the substitution? Intuitively if when we substitute a math object in a math statement with another equivalent object the resulting new math statement should be equivalent as before. Is there a better or simpler explanation for this? And is there an axiom?

Comment: Short and perhaps not satisfying answer: in a world where $a=4$, we have that $a+b=10$ is entirely equivalent to $4+b=10$.

Comment: No, there's no better explanation. Yes, there is an [axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: The way Leibniz defines equality, for any $x$, $y$ one has ($x=y$) iff (for any predicate $P$ one has $P(x)\iff P(y)$).  I.e. in any statement, any occurrence of $x$ can be replaced with something that $x$ is (*identically*) equal to without changing the truth of that statement and vice versa.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's pretty smart to include substitution property as part of the definition of equality. How convenient is that...

Comment: @NeedForHelp Okay..I might be hallucination when I thought there might be a better explanation.

Comment: @Arthur I get your point...

Comment: The source is ancient Greek mathematicians who recognized that if you perform the same operation (e.g., subtract 4.0) on both sides of an equation you get an equation.

Comment: @David The ancient Greeks didn't know about equations. That was the Arab contribution. Algebra (al'jabr).

Comment: @MattSamuel:  So how did Pythagoras express $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, for instance?

Comment: @David The square you could draw on the hypotenuse of a given right triangle has the same content as the two squares you could draw on the legs.

Comment: @David https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Compendious_Book_on_Calculation_by_Completion_and_Balancing

Comment: @MarkS.:  "It is sometimes alleged that the Greeks had no algebra, but this is inaccurate."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_algebra#Greek_geometric_algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "equation":

> $a + b =10$

is ambiguous. What are we asserting, when stating it ?

Probably not: $\forall a \ \forall b \ (a+b=10)$, which is quite useless.

Stating the problem as: "given $a + b =10$ and let $a=4$, find $b$", sounds like:

> check if $\exists b \ (a+b=10)$ is satisfiable in a certain *domain* (like e.g. $\mathbb N$) when $a=4$.

In this case the question is meaningful; we substitute $4$ for $a$ (foramlly: we instantiate a free variable with a value) and get: $\exists b \ (4+b=10)$ which is satisfied in $\mathbb N$ for $b=6$.

---

In a formal way, we have to use (as per comment above) the [first-order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) substitution axiom (for formulas):

> $x=y \to (\varphi \to \varphi')$

where $\varphi'$ is obtained by replacing any number (not necessarily all) of the free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ with $y$.

To be pedantic, we have first to prove (by induction) the "generalized form":

> $t_1=t_2 \to (\varphi \to \varphi')$

with $t_i$ *terms*, because $4$ is not a variable in the language of first-order arithmetic.

Now the substitution will be:

1) $a+b=10$ --- it is $\varphi$

2) $a=4$

3) $\vdash a=4 \to ((a+b=10) \to (4+b=10))$ ---suitable instance of the equality substituion axiom

> 4) $4+b=10$ --- it is $\varphi'$ : from 1),2) and 3) by *modus ponens* twice.